# std::stringstream reasignment works on Visual Studio 2013 but not under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, stringstream

I was just trying to compile the following code on Linux after having perfect success on Windows:

```
std::string str = stream.str();

auto decrement = [](char c) { return c - 100; };

std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), decrement);
stream = std::stringstream(str); // LINE ACCUSING ERROR
```

The error I receive for trying to reasign the std::stringstream is:

> 158: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_stringstream&
>   std::basic_stringstream::operator=(const
>   std::basic_stringstream&)'   stream = std::stringstream(str);
>            ^

Comment: What's your Linux compiler version? Does it support C++11?

Comment: Found the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27152263/3093378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stringstream` is not copyable, but can be only moved (since C++11). My guess is that you use g++4.9 or earlier, which even if it supports C++11, it doesn't fully support the move semantics for streams. g++5 and later compiles your code.

Reported bug dates back to 4.7, fixed in 5.x https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316

Comment: I updated to g++5 and my code compiles. But now it won't even get past the start. It fails to create a thread on `std::thread`. How do I update the STL?

Comment: Try using -pthread . Not sure otherwise, maybe try a minimal example and ask a different question.