# Workaround for returning uncopyable object without a move ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics, gcc4.9

In my API I have a function that returns `std::istringstream`.
The [`std::istringstream` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) is non-copyable but supports moving so on a conforming compiler there is no problem returning a local `std::istringstream`.

However, on gcc 4.9, there is [no support](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) for moving `std::istringstream`. 
Is there some workaround that I can use that `std::istringstream` without changing the API from the user's perspective?

The workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27152585/135862), of using a `unique_ptr<std::istringstream>` will change the semantics of the API.

Comment: I do not see how you can have a workaround if you cannot change the return type.

Comment: Well, say I take the result with `auto` (or just use it as a temporary) - so you could return something else. I now think it's possible to create a wrapper with the same interface and return that.

Comment: The wrapper would hit the same problem.  You cannot move the stream into the wrapper and you cannot copy it so how do you get the wrapper out of the function?

Comment: Since this is a workaround anyway, a colleague suggested that I could just *copy* the ios state and the stream buffer in the wrapper copy-ctor (or move-ctor). This will get the code to work correctly on the older compiler with some potential performance cost. If he doesn't post his solution I will.

Comment: @xaxxon: read the OP: on gcc 4.9 there's a bug and it doesn't.

Comment: @AdiShavit You say `unique_ptr<std::istringstream>` will change the semantics of the API, but wouldn't returning a wrapper change them just as much? You're changing the return type in both cases.

Comment: don't use 4.9 then.  That's the answer to the question as posed.

Comment: @xaxxon: thank you, that is very helpful.

Comment: The API is nonsensical if istringstream cannot be moved.   So by not changing the API, there's nothing to do if it cannot be moved.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Especially, is there a specific reason you cannot return the stream via reference/const reference? Do you really need the move behavior in your API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for completeness and future reference.

The goal was to find a *workaround* for the gcc (< 5) bug where `std::istringstream` does not provide a move ctor that will work in cases where I want to return the un-copyable and (bugly-) unmovable stream.
As mentioned in the comments, I can in fact change my function signature (at least on gcc < 5) to return a proxy object that allows copying or moving without changing the API for code used on newer/other compilers.

The idea, suggested and implemented by a colleague, is to create a proxy object around `std::istringstream` which provides a similar API, but also provides a copy-ctor which manually creates and initializes a new internal `std::istringstream` from the copied-from stream. This proxy is used only on the offending compilers.

The code in its natural habitat is [here](https://github.com/adishavit/argh/blob/master/argh.h#L25).
Here's the relevant part:

```
#if !defined(__GNUC__) || (__GNUC__ >= 5)
   using string_stream = std::istringstream;
#else
    // Until GCC 5, istringstream did not have a move constructor.
    // stringstream_proxy is used instead, as a workaround.
   class stringstream_proxy
   {
   public:
      stringstream_proxy() = default;

      // Construct with a value.
      stringstream_proxy(std::string const& value) :
         stream_(value)
      {}

      // Copy constructor.
      stringstream_proxy(const stringstream_proxy& other) :
         stream_(other.stream_.str())
      {
         stream_.setstate(other.stream_.rdstate());
      }

      void setstate(std::ios_base::iostate state) { stream_.setstate(state); }

      // Stream out the value of the parameter.
      // If the conversion was not possible, the stream will enter the fail state,
      // and operator bool will return false.
      template<typename T>
      stringstream_proxy& operator >> (T& thing)
      {
         stream_ >> thing;
         return *this;
      }


      // Get the string value.
      std::string str() const { return stream_.str(); }

      std::stringbuf* rdbuf() const { return stream_.rdbuf(); }

      // Check the state of the stream. 
      // False when the most recent stream operation failed
      operator bool() const { return !!stream_; }

      ~stringstream_proxy() = default;
   private:
      std::istringstream stream_;
   };
   using string_stream = stringstream_proxy;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move the `std::istringstream`, there's no much way around it.

If an object is non copiable and non movable, you can't return it by value.
If you want to support new features, you better get a new compiler for those.

In the meatime, you could return a `unique_ptr`. If you're really eager to return by value, you could return a movable wrapper that contains a `std::unique_ptr<std::istringstream>` and provide the same interface as a istringstream. However, this also affect the return type.

---

It may be tempting to return by rvalue reference. Here's what you can do:

```
struct MyApiClass {

    std::istringstream&& get_stream() {
        return std::move(*_stream);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::istringstream> _stream;
};
```

Then, with your old compiler, you can use it like this:

```
std::istringstream&& stream = myApiClass.get_stream();

// use stream as long as myApiClass exists
```

People using a new compiler will be able to use it like that:

```
std::istringstream stream = myApiClass.get_stream();

// use stream normally
```

This is the way the api is less affected. Other than that, I don't know any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The way to return class without move/copy constructor is to use the return statement with braced-init-list:

```
class C {
    C() = default;
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C(C&&) = delete;
};

C make_C() { return {}; }

int main() {
    C&& c = make_C();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eac0fb729be80bae)

Unfortunately, only non-explicit constructor are considered for this initialization and `std::istringstream` have explicit constructor.

One workaround is to create a sub-class with non explicit constructor:

```
struct myIStringStream : std::istringstream
{
    myIStringStream () = default;
};

myIStringStream make_istringstream()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream&& iss = make_istringstream();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/gZlbSP)